# Laravel remote ssh very slow

Tags: php, linux, laravel, ssh, server

I am trying to get the git log from remote server with Laravel built in SSH feature. Everything works but it takes ~7 seconds to connect over SSH, get the log, convert commits into array and then display them in the view. I don't know if it is normal or I need another approach for this, maybe python, cgi ... 
This is the function that I have so far:

```
public function commits(){
    $commands = array(
        'cd /var/www/web1/public_html',
        'git log -8',
    );

    SSH::into('production')->run($commands, function($line)
    {
        $this->output .= $line.PHP_EOL;
    });
    $arr = explode("\n",$this->output);

    foreach ($arr as $line){
            // Clean Line
            $line = trim($line);
            // Proceed If There Are Any Lines
            if (!empty($line))
            {
                    // Commit
                    if (strpos($line, 'commit') !== false)
                    {
                            $hash = explode(' ', $line);
                            $hash = trim(end($hash));
                            $git_history[$hash] = [
                                    'message' => ''
                            ];
                            $last_hash = $hash;
                            $git_history[$last_hash]['hash'] = $last_hash;
                    }
                    // Author
                    else if (strpos($line, 'Author') !== false) {
                            $author = explode(':', $line);
                            $author = trim(end($author));
                            //email starts with < and ends with >
                            $pattern = sprintf(
                                    '/%s(.+?)%s/ims',
                                    preg_quote('<', '/'), preg_quote('>', '/')
                            );
                            //check pattern and assign the email of the author
                            if (preg_match($pattern, $author, $matches)) {
                                    list(, $match) = $matches;
                                    //echo $match;
                                    $git_history[$last_hash]['author'] = $match;
                                    $user = Sentry::findUserByLogin($git_history[$last_hash]['author']);
                                    $git_history[$last_hash]['avatar'] = $user->avatar;
                            }

                    }
                    // Date
                    else if (strpos($line, 'Date') !== false) {
                            $date = explode(':', $line, 2);
                            $date = trim(end($date));
                            $git_history[$last_hash]['date'] = date('d/m/Y H:i:s A', strtotime($date));
                    }
                    // Message
                    else {
                            $git_history[$last_hash]['message'] .= $line ." ";
                    }
            }
    }
    //$data['server_answer'] = $git_history;
    return Response::json($git_history);
}
```

Comment: I use something called as paramiko for all ssh work & I used flask instead of php with python, its relatively fast. Have you tried these?

Comment: @Suddev no I haven't, I am new to python too, but I am willing to learn it in case it gives a solution to my problem. I am going to need to run remote commands often so I need a better solution for me to run those commands from Laravel controllers

Comment: give that a try - and let me know - if paramiko makes it faster - I am still trying to understand your full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally do it with Paramiko, its easier

```
import paramiko

# ssh 
print 'enter ssh'
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()) # this will automatically add the keys
ssh.connect(machineHostName, username=user, password=password)

# Run your commands
# example 1 : ls command
print 'do a ls command'
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls')
print stdout.readlines()
time.sleep(2)
# example 2 : change ip address
print 'changing ip address'
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('sed -i -- s/'+oldIp+'/'+newIp+'/g /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0')
print stdout.readlines()
time.sleep(2)
```

To install Paramiko, you can download the tar.gz file from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paramiko/1.15.2).

Assuming you are really new to python, how to install this :

- Download the `tar.gz` file
- Extract the contents to a folder
- `cd` into that extracted folder, from your terminal
- execute this `python setup.py install`
- then you can try something like the above example

NOTE : if you get stuck with installation comment here, and I can help you.

Comment: nice syntax, but still if I do this and I have to execute it from PHP I am gonna have to do it with SSH which slow (it seems ssh is the problem). On the other hand if I use this or any other bash script and execute it with cURL maybe I dont have idea how to secure it from outside world. Some ideas come into my mind but yet it doesnt seem very secure way to me.

Comment: I had similar problems like u about a week back. PHP was not letting me SSH. So I replaced PHP with Python FLASK, its really easy. And regarding how secure this is - i am not really sure on that.

Comment: Do you want a code snippet - for Python Flask? Its really easy, and it can do the work of your PHP

Comment: I am going to keep your solution as backup if I don't find a solution that I am going to be sure it is secure and use it inside laravel controllers. I got the idea how python flask and paramiko work. thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up building a python API to execute commands in the server rather then connecting via SSH because using SSH library with PHP slows the web site a lot. With python executing commands and returning messages/errors it is a lot more faster (under 1 second).